# Discord bot and multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, discord

I'm currently implementing a discord bot using the [Rapptz library](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) and i'm facing a problem with mutlithreading. This is probably very easy, I'm missing something for sure!

I poll a list of twitch channels to see if they are up and if one of them is, I'd like the bot to send a message in a specific channel.
To do so I run a thread which polls every X seconds the Twitch API but I can't make the bot to send the message. I'm new to asynchronous programming so it's probably the reason.

Here a simplified example of what I'd like to do

```
class MyThread(Thread):

def __init__(self, client):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.client = client

def run(self):
    while True:
        self.client.send_message(channel, "Sending message every 10 seconds!")
        time.sleep(10)
```

The thing is I know that the `send_message` method is asynchronous but:

- When I put the `await` keyword in front of the `send_message` call, I need also to define the `run` method as a coroutine. When I try to run it I got the message. `RuntimeWarning: coroutine MyThread.run was never awaited`
- When I do not put it, I don't get errors but the message is still not sent.

I think that there is a thing to do with event loop but I'm completely lost. When I read article about asynchronous programming it seems pretty clear but I don't manage to adapt it to my problem...

Comment: I really don't think you need to be running your own threads when Rapptz's library uses asyncio already. You should look into the documentation of both Rapptz's and asyncio to figure out how to control the loops. With asyncio, you're essentially going to have to create a coroutine that gets placed into the event loop.

Also, if u do use asyncio with ur `run()` you will need to use `asyncio.sleep(10)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @xNinjaKittyx The thing is that the discord bot seems to be blocking the main thread while waiting for commands... I think i'm forced to use a thread since I'm guessing that the bot is always in a 'active listening' state so the twitch polling coroutine is never executed :(

Comment: The Client.run() command is blocking, so you can't run anything on the main thread afterwards. Rapptz put a way for people to manage the event loop themselves [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.run). Then you register your coroutine into the event loop. (probably in the `on_ready()` event). Another approach would be to use Command Extensions to create a command that does your while loop. Then invoke the command in the `on_ready()` event.